# Arraylist of Characters Unwantingly Turns in to Objects when Accessed

Tags: java, arraylist

beware: non-experienced coder...

I have an arraylist (named a) of arraylists (named b). b is an arraylist of characters. When I try to get a single character from the b by doing

```
a.get(0).get(0);
```

it gives me an error saying I'm giving it a object, not a character.

Comment: What is `a`'s type, including any generics?

Comment: Can you show where you define a and b? Can you show how you populate a and b?

Comment: Please post the code where you define a and b.

Comment: ArrayList<Character>b=new ArrayList<Character>();
ArrayList<ArrayList>a=new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

Answer (score 2):

Because the second `get` is returning an `Object`, the first `get` seems to return the `ArrayList` (or a `List`) properly.  The most likely explanation is that you have a partially generic, partially raw `ArrayList`, presumably of the type `ArrayList<ArrayList>`.  The generic type parameter `ArrayList` is itself a raw type, meaning it will return an `Object` upon a call to `get`.  Another possibility is that you have an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>`.

Fully specify the generic type, nesting generics all the way down to the scalar type.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> a;
```

Answer (score 1):

That is nature of [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). If you don't specify type of elements in your `a` list in your case using

```
List<List<Character>> a;
```

but instead you will use raw type

```
List a;
```

compiler can only assume that you are storing `Objects` so result of `get()` will also be assumed to be `Object` which doesn't have any `get()`

```
a.get(0).get(0)
       //^-this method can't be invoked from reference of Object type
```

Comment: So if I have
    ArrayList<Character>a=new ArrayList<Character>(); 

What should I change it to?

Comment: @user3268099 If your `a` list should be list that contains list of characters you need to declare and initialize it with `ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>>();`

Comment: @user3268099 In short: type of list which contains characters should be `List<Character>`, Type of list that contains lists of characters should be `List<List<Character>>`.